# Internet Explorer Script Error while opening modal dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, modal-dialog

I have an ASP.NET web form having GridView control, being used as a lookup form for some primary data. So I have opened it as modal.

```
returnValue = window.showModalDialog(url, "", "dialogWidth:" + width + "px; dialogHeight:" + height + "px; center:yes");
```

The GridView displays multiple columns from the underlying data source (SQL Server). As some data source value contains *<del>comma (,)</del>* apostrophe **(')** the page shows Internet Explorer Script Error

```
Error: Expected ')'
```

However, if I change the JavaScript window opening statement to `window.open` it works fine.

I tried to google the issue, but didn't find relevant results.

**UPDATE 1**
That too only happening in IE. In Firefox it is working well with modal dialog also.

**UPDATE 2** *@MelanciaUK*
This is my data fetching and binding logic

```
        IMessage _objMsg = _objEntity.GetAll();
        IEnumerable<istb_generalInfo> _objList = (IEnumerable<istb_generalInfo>)_objMsg.GetList();

        gvLookup.DataSource = _objList;
        gvLookup.DataBind();
```

**UPDATE 3**
I misunderstood slightly. The IE Script Error is being shown when any string contains apostrophe (') and not comma (,). I have corrected this in the text above also.

Also the error message changes to `Unterminated string constant` when string ends with apostrophe ('). And if string contains apostrophe in between text the error message shows as `Expected ')'`

Comment: If its working in firefox then it seems its not problem with above code but there might be error at different place in same file having javascript code. Please see error location in console of dev-tools(f12) in IE that might help.

Comment: @Pranav Its even working without modal dialog in IE (i.e. with normal window.open). Then what would you say? :). Anyways, it seems that DevTools (F12) and View Source doesn't work with IE modal dialog. Do they?

Comment: Just put the string as @"", instead of just "". May solve your problem. Or use HtmlEncode().

Comment: @MelanciaUK I didn't understand how could I? I am just extracting the data from source using EF query and binding it to the GridView. Please view the relevant code in the udpate above.